# Magento 2.3 - How to pass array from controller to template

Tags: magento2.3, controllers, array, custom-template

I am working on a custom module. I am getting array of attribute values in my custom controller and I want to pass these values in my template to list in a select dropdown. Please provide a solution -

**Controller -**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $Urlparam =  $this->getRequest()->getParam('make');
        echo $Urlparam;
        $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('id');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('model');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('status');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('make',5711);
        //$count =0;
        $modelValues[] = "";
        foreach ($collection as $product) {
            $modelValue = $product->getAttributeText("model");;
            if ((in_array($modelValue,$modelValues)) == false) {
                $modelValues[] = $modelValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Block file -**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Vendor extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('id');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('make');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('status');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1);

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

**Template file -**

```
<select class="select-model">
    <option>Select Model</option> 
</select>
```

I am new to this concept. Please provide a solution for how to show the array from the controller in phtml select option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Registry `\Magento\Framework\Registry` you can pass the parameters from the controller to Block. At 2.3, Registry is deprecated but still, you can use.

Inject the **registry class** to your controller class `__construct`

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) {
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->registry =  $registry;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

$modelValue to registry a variable. Add below code after for each loop of at your controller's execute() method.

```
if ($this->registry->registry('makes_info')) {
    $this->registry->unregister('makes_info');
}
// set value to registry variable  makes_info
$this->registry->register('makes_info', $modelValues);
```

After that Inject the **registry class** to your Block class `__construct`

At same way and

After that access that registry variable below way

```
if ($this->registry->registry('makes_info')) {
    $makes_info = $this->registry->registry('makes_info');
}
```

Comment: please provide detailed solution. As how to implement in controller and template.

Comment: and how to get that in tempalte file select option?

Comment: `$block->getRequest()->getParam('make')` is same as `$Urlparam =  $this->getRequest()->getParam('make');` at phtml